# Migrate DataStage Job in to ADF,Subscriptions required and any plugins needed

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, subscription, datastage

We have a DataStage Job which currently does simple transform from 3 different On Prem Sql DB Sources in to single destination SQL source(On Prem) again.We are planning to migrate Datastage in to ADF.Have the below questions as I am newbie to ADF.
1)How do request for Azure subscription with ADF enabled?
2)Since the source and destination are on Prem DB Servers,does this require any plug ins or framework to allow the connections between Azure and OnPrem servers

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to on-prem sources directly from ADF using a self-hosted Integration Runtime. To set that up, it will require installation of a service executable on a server or VM that has connectivity to your on-prem data. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime